# Appcelerator Emulator not loading

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I have installed Appcelerator and the required SDK but the emulator still doesn't load on the screen.

It comes up with this error:

> [ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1
>
> [ERROR] :  Emulator exited with error: 1
>
> [ERROR] :  PANIC: ANDROID_SDK_HOME is defined but could not find titanium_1_WVGA800.ini file in $ANDROID_SDK_HOME.android\avd
>
> [ERROR] :  (Note: avd is searched in the order of $ANDROID_AVD_HOME,$ANDROID_SDK_HOME.android\avd and $HOME.android\avd)

Appreciate any help.

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at https://www.genymotion.com

It's free and much faster than the normal Android simulator.

I know, this is not a correct answer, but it's definitely the better and faster way to develop for Android under Appcelerator

Answer (score 0):

Try to check you enviroment variables;
For example i have this path in variable "Path":

```
C:\android-sdk-win\platform-tools;
C:\android-sdk-win\tools;
C:\android-sdk-win
```

Do you have the same situation?

I think that your problem is that there isn't a good link with the emulator's file

Answer (score 0):

What helped me to solve the problem was:

- Delete all with Android Studio created Emulators.
- Delete all with Genymotion created Emulators.

Then create one new Genymotion Emulator. Try it again.